# Setting options in a method call with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I make it so the `.slider()` method uses the values from the array?

I have this same slider I have to set up several times, so I figured I would call it once, and input the values with the index. This might not be the way to do it but it's what came to me.

I wanted to step through and change the index number each time I call the slider so it would update to the next 6 values. I realize this code doesn't work, it's just for explaining.

```
var yolo = ["yield", "true", "15.2", "308", "0.3", "[75.8, 241.4]", "tensile", "true", "37.7", "345", "[81.2, 243.3]"];

     $( yolo[0] ).slider({
        range: yolo[1],
        min: yolo[2],
        max: yolo[3],
        step : yolo[4],
        values: yolo[5],

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#" + yolo[0] + "-value" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
     }); //When done, call again, just that updating the index numbers to the next 6
```

Maybe an `.each()` with `$.extend()`?

Comment: This will return text, not an array: `"[75.8, 241.4]"`

Comment: You could use a two dimensional array, which holds arrays of the config 6 values. Option two would be something like doing a for cycle with the increment 6: for (i = 0; i < yolo.length; i += 6) {} and then you use the array index like 0+i, 1+i, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as:

```
var settings = {
    "yield" : {
         range: true,
         etc..
    },
    "yield2" : {
         range: true,
         etc..
    }
}

$.each(settings, function(key, value){
    var _key = key;
    $( "#" + _key ).slider(
        $.extend(value, {    
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#" + _key + "-value" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Extra info:

1. [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)
2. [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

use .each http://api.jquery.com/each/ to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array, you can just use a plain object:

```
var yolo = {
   range : true,
   min : 15.2,
   max : 308,
   slide : function(){}
};
```

and then pass that into slider.

```
$(...).slider(yolo);
```